# how can I count in an array

Tags: php, mysql

tearing my hair out... how to I sum the numbers in the following array, tried this but it didn't work. I even tried it inside the loop but i get nothing. I don't think it should that difficult but for some reason I can't get this.

```
$sql = "SELECT queue_name,type,COUNT(uniqueid) AS calls FROM CallLog WHERE start_time     BETWEEN '2013-10-14 00:00:00' AND '2013-10-14 23:59:59' GROUP BY queue_name, type";

$stmt=$dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

$calls = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach($calls as $call){
$results[ $call['queue_name'] ][ $call['type'] ] = $call['calls'];

}

$totalCalls = array_sum($call['calls']);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($results);
echo '</pre>';
echo $totalCalls;
?>
```

```
Array
    (
    [Escalations] => Array
    (
        [abandoned] => 2
        [completed] => 3
        [redirected] => 1
    )

[Premium] => Array
    (
        [abandoned] => 7
        [completed] => 29
        [redirected] => 6
    )

[Standard] => Array
    (
        [abandoned] => 14
        [completed] => 41
        [redirected] => 53
    )

[Wingate Queue] => Array
    (
        [abandoned] => 2
        [completed] => 3
    )

[WorldMark] => Array
    (
        [abandoned] => 32
        [completed] => 100
        [redirected] => 82
    )

    )
```

Comment: Do you want to sum ALL the numbers, or just one sum for abandoned, one for completed etc?

Comment: thank you! I would like to sum all the number so I can use the total to calculate percentages.

Comment: I think you need to add a rollup with the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bug in your code:

```
    $totalCalls = array_sum($call['calls']); 
// $call['calls'] is just a single value not an array
```

Simplest way is to:

```
$totalCalls = 0;
foreach($calls as $call){
$results[ $call['queue_name'] ][ $call['type'] ] = $call['calls'];
$totalCalls += $call['calls'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$results = array(
    'Escalations' => array('abandoned' => 2,'completed' => 3,'redirected' => 1),
    'Premium' => array('abandoned' => 7,'completed' => 29,'redirected' => 6),
    'Standard' => array('abandoned' => 14,'completed' => 41,'redirected' => 53),
    'Wingate Queue' => array('abandoned' => 2,'completed' => 3),
    'WorldMark' => array('abandoned' => 32,'completed' => 100,'redirected' => 82)
);

$total_calls = 0;
foreach($results as $k=>$v){
    $total_calls += array_sum($v);
}

echo $total_calls;
```

Answer (score 1):

`$call` is not defined outside of your `for` loop:

```
$totalCalls = array_sum($call['calls']);
                        ^^^^^
```

You could just sum it in the loop:

```
$totalCalls = 0;
foreach($calls as $call){
    $results[ $call['queue_name'] ][ $call['type'] ] = $call['calls'];
    $totalCalls += $call['calls'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try this one

```
$totalCalls = 0;
foreach($calls as $call){
    $results[ $call['queue_name'] ][ $call['type'] ] = $call['calls'];
    $totalCalls += $call['calls'];
}
```

Comment: `$call['calls']` isn't array.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in your SQL query if you do not need the rest of the data elsewhere.

Something along the lines of:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(uniqueid) AS total
FROM 
    CallLog 
WHERE
    start_time BETWEEN '2013-10-14 00:00:00' AND '2013-10-14 23:59:59'
GROUP BY 
    queue_name, type";
```

Keep in mind this will return a single number, and not all the data you previously had.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way of counting all the calls can be doing this:

```
$totalCalls = 0;
foreach($calls as $call){
    $totalCalls += array_sum($call);
}
```

This will count all the items.